# ASP.NET route with fixed URI not mapping querystring parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta with Web API - although I believe the routing implementation has no significant differences from .NET 4.0 relevant to this question. `MapHttpRoute`, used in the code below, ships with MVC 4 and is an extension method that essentially performs the same function as MapRoute, but for WebApi controllers.

I have a legacy web serivce method for which I want create an ASP.NET route. The method currently has following signature:

```
NewsItemList ListNewsItems(string category, int maxResults)
```

It should be mapped by requests whose URIs look like this:

```
~/news?category=finance&maxResults=50
```

Neither, either or both query string parameters can be present.

I am struggling to find a way to define a route to support this method.

I used `MapHttpRoute` to register the route and set defaults for the controller and action values to the controller and method appropriately. Here are some templates I have tried with the outcome:

- `"news"` captures `"~/news"` and binds to the method correctly, but
  won't capture anything with a querystring.
- `"news{*query}` is not
  allowed because you cannot have a catch-all unless it is exclusive to
  the Uri segment
- `"news{query}"` captures the query string but doesn't
  bind to the method

I'm looking for a way forwards that isn't too radical a departure as this is an edge-case in the application. The solution has to fit in with many other existing routes. Ideally I'd like to avoid going down the Uri re-writer path as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was down to a problem in the way I was testing. I erroneously assumed that `HttpRequestBase.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath` includes the query string part of the request uri. It does not. When I corrected my Mock, everything started working.